# Вывод из списка нужное значение

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь по *Javascript*.

У меня есть допустим три списка, и входящие в него параметры.

Оружие:

1. `Pistol: usp, glock, p250`
2. `Automat: ak47, m4a1, famas`
3. `Snipe: awp, scout`

Допустим мне приходит с сервера `usp`, мне необходимо вывести `Pistol`, приходит `ak47` значит `Automat`.

Как решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function in_array(item, array) {
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] == item) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

var parents = {
  Pistol: [1, 2, 3],
  Automat: [4, 5, 6],
  Snipe: [7, 8, 9]
};

var what_do_you_need = 5; // need to return Automat

for(key in parents) {
  if(in_array(what_do_you_need, parents[key])) console.log(key); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Доброе утро, попробуй использовать сравнение по Map

```
var guns = [
    {firstname : "Automat", lastname: "ak47"},
    {firstname : "Pistol", lastname: "ups"}
];

function getFullName(item,index) {
    var fullname = [item.lastname].join(" ");
    return fullname;
}
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = guns.map(getFullName);
}
```

Comment: Павел, если бы я знал как именно, про метод знаю а как правильно его применить в этом случае не знаю( пример нужен...

Comment: @Members, это должно вас навести на правильную мысль

Comment: Что то не совсем что нужно, повторю еще раз,

Comment: У меня прилетает допустим с match[1] m4a1, у меня есть список массивом , Automat, в него входят параметры m4a1,ak47.. второй Pistol, в нем usp,glock, так вот мне приход с match[1] m4a1 скрипт смотрит входящие параметры, если это m4a1 значит выводим Automat, если glock значит выводим Pistol

Comment: как я понял, у тебя есть 1 массив - автомат{ak47,m16,...}, 2 массив - пистолет{colt, colt2,...} и ты хочешь сортировать массив по названию оружия?

Comment: ну да почти, у меня есть массив с автоматами, массив с пистолетами, если мне допустим с переменной match[1] приходит m4a1 то мне в консоль выводит Автомат, если usp то пистолет

Comment: Результат приходит с одной переменной match[1], если его результат m4a1 и он есть в массиве, то мне выводит автомат в консоль, если usp то пистолет в консоль

Comment: var weapon = 'ak47';


var guns = ["ak47", 'm4a1'];
var guns2 = ["usp", 'cl'];

var hs = guns.indexOf(weapon) !== -1 ? true : false;

if(hs == true){
console.log('automat');
} else if (guns2.indexOf(weapon) !== -1 ? true : false){
console.log('pistol');
} else {
console.log('awp');
}